# Issue with layouts position/dimensions before they are getting displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a piece of code where I am displaying some pins (`Button` with an image) on an image (full screen `ImageView`). (You can assume that all the pins are created dynamically and have a random position). The requirement is that those pins should not overlap. For each pin created I am checking if it overlaps with any of the other previously created pins.

To do that I am trying to get the `Rect` of those pins and check if they overlap using `Rect.intersects()`.
The issue is that I cannot use functions like `getRight()`, `getTop()`, `getWidth()`, `getHeight()` before the view is actually displayed. They all return 0. So I cannot get the correct data for the rectangles.
I tried to put the code in different callbacks like `onWindowFocusChanged()` or `onResume()` but I still got the same issue, all dimensions/positions return 0.

I am looking for a solution/advice regarding this problem. How to get the correct positions and dimensions before the pins are displayed ?

I looked at `View.measure()`, it seems I can get some values using `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` but `getRight()` and `getTop()` still return 0.

Comment: Look at the answers of [Android get width returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3591784/1190651)

Answer (score 0):

Add invisible rect first and check the position then move this position as per requirements and the make this visible. This will do the trick.